# How to analyze memory leak from coredump

Tags: c, coredump, gcore

I would like to analyze a memory leak from core file analysis.

I have written sample code to inject memory leak and generate core file with gcore command.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void fun()
{
  int *ptr = new int(1234);
}
int main()
{
  int i=0;
  while(i++<2500)
  {
    fun();
}
sleep(360);
return 0;
}
```

Find the process ID

```
ayadav@ajay-PC:~$ ps -aef |grep over  
ajay      8735  6016  0 12:57 pts/2    00:00:00 ./over  
ayadav    8739  4659  0 12:57 pts/10   00:00:00 grep over
```

and generated core

```
ayadav@ajay-PC:~$ sudo gcore 8735
[sudo] password for ayadav:
0x00007fbb7dda99a0 in __nanosleep_nocancel () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: No such file or directory.
Saved corefile core.8735
```

I have found common patterns from core file as below(as suggested on stackoverflow another thread [Is there a way to locate which part of the process used the most of the memory, only looking at a generated core file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710404/is-there-a-way-to-locate-which-part-of-the-process-used-the-most-of-the-memory))

```
ayadav@ajay-PC:~$ hexdump core.6015 | awk '{printf "%s%s%s%s\n%s%s%s%s\n", $5,$4,$3,$2,$9,$8,$7,$6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
6913 0000000000000000  
2503 0000002100000000  
2501 000004d200000000  
786 0000000000007ffc  
464  
125 1ccbc4d000007ffc  
 92 1ca7ead000000000  
 91 0000000200007ffc  
 89 0000000100007ffc  
 80 0000000100000000
```

Below two addresses are suspected one

```
2503 0000002100000000  
2501 000004d200000000
```

core file have following repeated patterns

```
0003560 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
0003570 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
0003580 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
0003590 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
00035a0 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
00035b0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
00035c0 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
00035d0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
00035e0 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
00035f0 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
0003600 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
0003610 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
0003620 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000  
0003630 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  
0003640 0000 0000 0021 0000 0000 0000 04d2 0000
```

But I do not have much idea how I can access it from command like gdb info address or x.
Could anybody tell how I can convert symbol information from binary format?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core dump file analysis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115613/core-dump-file-analysis)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to analyze a program's core dump file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8305866/how-to-analyze-a-programs-core-dump-file)

Comment: Based on your use of `new` I'd say this is C++, not C. However you are `#include`ing `<stdlib.h>`, not `<cstdlib>`, so I don't really know what language your program is written in...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1 - Memory leaks can be evaluated with a core dump. I have taken a sample c++ example:

```
class Base  
{  
public:  
    virtual void fun(){}  
    virtual void xyz(){}  
    virtual void lmv(){}  
    virtual void abc(){}  
};  

class Derived: public Base  
{  
public:  
    void fun(){}  
    void xyz(){}  
    void lmv(){}  
    void abc(){}  
};  

void fun()  
{  
    Base *obj  = new Derived();  
}  
int main()  
{  
    for(int i = 0; i < 2500;i++)
    {
        fun();
    }
    sleep(3600);
    return 0; 
}
```

2 - Created a core with gcore command

3 - Search the repeated pattern from core file.

```
ayadav@ajay-PC:~$ hexdump core.10639 | awk '{printf "%s%s%s%s\n%s%s%s%s\n", $5,$4,$3,$2,$9,$8,$7,$6}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr  | head
   6685 0000000000000000  
   2502 0000002100000000  
   2500 004008d000000000  
    726 0000000000007eff  
    502   
    125 2e4314d000007eff  
     93 006010d000000000  
     81 0000000100007eff  
     80 0000000100000000  
     73 0000000000000001
```

`0000002100000000` and `004008d000000000`  are repeated patterns

4 - Check each qword is what with?

```
(gdb) info symbol ...
(gdb) x ...
```

example:

```
(gdb) info symbol 0x4008d000
No symbol matches 0x4008d000.
(gdb) info symbol 0x4008d0
vtable for Derived + 16 in section .rodata of /home/ayadav/virtual
```

5 - Probably most frequent vtable must relate to memory leak i.e Derived vtable.

Note: I agree coredump analysis is not best practice to find memory leak. Memory leak can be find with different static and dynamic tools like valgrind etc.

Comment: I like the Unix way of thinking, but I would have to say that it should be possible to figure out what kinds of allocations are currently active in the core file... After a quick look at Google the [core analyzer](http://core-analyzer.sourceforge.net/) came up.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to identify whether a process is causing memory leak or not directly looking at the core dump. Infact, there is no thing called memory leak as such, we can not make that comment with out knowing the programmers intention for writing the code. having said that, you can get an idea by looking at the size of the core dump. You can generate multiple dumps say, one after initial run and one after prolonged run and if you see a vast difference in size, one can guess there could be something going wrong. But again, the memory could be used for productive purposes.

For the actual analysis and tracking of memory leak, one should be using tools like, memtrack, valgrind etc to add wrappers over malloc and free to give extra information about each alloc and free.

Update:

As you are looking for the hex analysis, here is what I can see:
Your every line is 16 bytes and repeated in two lines. That is 32 bytes a chunk. 0x4D2 is 1234 in decimal. So, your data is there. It could be possible that your one alloc chunk is 32 bytes. Check and print the address in hex after every 'new()' and compare to see if you are observing a 32 bytes gap and then it explains it.

Comment: Hi Joe,  As answered on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8710404/is-there-a-way-to-locate-which-part-of-the-process-used-the-most-of-the-memory. It is possible to find memory leak from coredump. I agree i can use tools like Valgrind but for my understanding i would like to analysis from core file.

Comment: updated answer as your request. But I don't think this is the right way to debug a memory leak.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thank you very much for suggestion. yes alloc chunk is 32 bytes gap. 0x12c4010
0x12c4030
0x12c4050
0x12c4070
0x12c4090
0x12c40b0
0x12c40d0
0x12c40f0
0x12c4110
0x12c4130
0x12c4150
0x12c4170    but i have one more doubt how i can see allocation which are not referenced

Comment: "Infact, there is no thing called memory leak as such, we can not make that comment with out knowing the programmers intention for writing the code."

I would say that is somewhat true, but if someone has dynamically allocated memory that they no longer retain any pointers to, as in the question's example, then it's a memory leak.